# Does jpeg compression destroys any embedded malicious code inside an image?

Tags: image, jpeg, photos, virus

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to "clean" images that are coming from non authorized source (app visitors) before opening them, similar to Whatsapp.
Scanning each image with anti virus is probably not so efficient in a large scale, So i came to assumption that rewriting each incoming image by compressing it using jpeg could results a clean image without a malicous code inside it.
From what i read so far the JPEG compression should destroy any hidden content and reorder the data structure of the image which will results a safe image.

WTYT? Am i on the right path to overcome this issue?

Comment: Chicken versus egg. To rewrite the image you will have to open it, and opening it is what the virus author wants you to do...

Comment: You think that rewriting each file with compression is going to be more efficient than letting your AV software scan it for you? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: My plan is to use ImageMagick for this purpose, do you think by converting an image to jpeg a malicious code can be triggered? (after patching the ImageMagick latest vulnerable :)) @barny

Comment: It's not the only reason for that, using ClamAV we have found that embedded code like "cmd.exe" is not considered as a malicious but we are afraid of cases when renaming such file to exe will yield a cmd exe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about information security rather than programming

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in a JPEG stream. In fact, I don't know of any image format that directs the decoder execute code.

The worst think I can thing of would be to have a JPEG stream that, say embedded malicious code in a thumbnail, COM, or APPn marker. Then another application would look for that image and load the code.

Even this requires something else to get on your system to execute the JPEG "code" and it would be a lot of trouble for something that could be accomplished much easier.

Comment: There are examples online of embedding malicious code in images. The examples I've seen aren't triggered by the image decoder itself, but by tricking another piece of software into "executing" the image file.